"InvalidArgumentError missing field 'capabilities'" after mozilla geckodriver updated to 0.35v
Last week Mozilla's geckodriver released the new 0.35.0 version, and since then the tests I'm running using Jenkins aren't running.
In the console output I've noticed the error that I put on the title:

E/launcher - InvalidArgumentError: missing field 'capabilities'

In the documentation of the new release, it says that they

Removed support for session negotiation using the deprecated
desiredCapabilities and requiredCapabilities.

(Full documentation: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases )
Looking at my protractor.conf.js file, I tried to changed it from "multiCapabilities" into "Capabilites". Or, to show this part of the code in its fully, from
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'firefox',
    unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {    
      args: [ "--headless" ]
    }]

into
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {    
      args: [ "--headless" ]
    }

but unfortunately it didn't solve it, and the "missing field capabilities" error still appeared.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks :)
